# How to make my input fields glow with dijit and dojo in a Springs Web Flow Project

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, dojo, spring-webflow

I am working on a Spring Web Flow Project and I would like to use Dojo dijit css to make my input form and fields nice.   I would like to make my fields glow.

The have the following on top of my JSP:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<c:url value="/resources/dojo/dojo.js" />"> </script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<c:url value="/resources/spring/Spring.js" />"> </script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<c:url value="/resources/spring/Spring-Dojo.js" />"> </script>

<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="<c:url value="/resources/dijit/themes/claro/claro.css" />" />
```

but how do I change my Spring form:input tags to use them and glow?

can someone please tell me how to change the following

```
<form:input tabIndex="3"  maxLength="15" size="16" path="first_name" />
```

so it would glow... thansk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was missing the

```
<body class="claro">
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you mean by "glow"but to use dojo css you need to add something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    Spring.addDecoration(new Spring.ElementDecoration({
        elementId : "first_name",
        widgetType : "dijit.form.ValidationTextBox",
        widgetAttrs : { required : true }}));
</script>
```

Comment: how does it now on the submit to check this

Comment: if you are talking about how to check required fields on the submit
<script type="text/javascript">
    Spring.addDecoration(new Spring.ValidateAllDecoration({elementId:'buttonId', event:'onclick'}));
</script>

Comment: yes but one of them are a radiobutton and I cant get it working!